# Unable to prevent zoom on iPhone with initial-scale=1

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, responsive-design

I'm converting a previously fixed-width design to responsive.

1. I modified the layout to use %s and added media queries.
2. I added the viewport meta tag: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`
3. Everything works great when I shrink the browser window.
4. Everything still works great when I use Google Chrome's emulator

**BUT** when I test using an actual iPhone, there is extra width which causes a horizontal scroll.

What am I doing wrong?

Here are two live demos:

http://secretdesignproject.com/demo/ts/1/index.php/screen/index/941065

http://secretdesignproject.com/demo/ts/1/index.php/screen/index/691674

Answer (score 0):

Usually your must complement your responsive design with media query's and there your can restrict browser behaviors with css, just for your phone rendering

```
@media (max-width: 640px){
     /*your css code here*/
}
```

try it...

[here is a good reference for media queries](http://cssmediaqueries.com/)

Good luck,

Comment: This was done extensively. Sorry if that wasn't clear from the question.